# Jasmine testing if the observer's next has been called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a BehaviourSubject:

```
   public dataObserver = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

and when I receive data in a subscribe block I call next on this:

```
       this.dataObserver.next(response);
```

I am facing issue in writing unit test case for testing that if next has been called or not. Kindly help me out. I tried to find in existing questions but did not find any. Kindly reply with link of relevant question on stack overflow if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
spyOn(component.dataObserver, 'next').and.callThrough(); // and.callThrough() is optional
// put it if you want next to be called with its actual implementation
....
expect(component.dataObserver.next).toHaveBeenCalled(); // you can also use .toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```